# Large mixed integer programming in R - possible to solve?

Tags: r, mixed-integer-programming, lpsolve

I would like to solve a large mixed integer programming problem, and I have tried with R, package lpSolveAPI. The problem is large - 410 variables each of which can be either 0 or 1, and about 49422 constraints. I have tried to let it run for 1,5 days, but once I try to stop it, it says that R needs to be terminated. The same happens if I let it run for short time, say 15 minutes, and then try to stop it by clicking on the red button. Since this happens, I am not sure whether there is something wrong with my computer or whether such problem is way too large for a computer. When it runs, it uses maybe 20% of the CPU power and about 70% of memory. My computer is a 2022 Lenovo X1 Yoga with i7 2.80GHz processor and 16GB of ram.

The problem itself is constructed in the following way:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
#A has length of 410. No constraints to begin with
lprec <- make.lp(0, 410)
set.objfn(lprec, round(A,0))
lp.control(lprec, sense="max")
set.type(lprec,c(1:A),"binary")

#Defining the constraints with a for loop. Will not go into details, but it adds 49422 constraints

for (){
...
      add.constraint(lprec, MyConstraint, "<=", 1)
...
}

lprec
#This says: Model name: a linear program with 410 decision variables and 49422 constraints

solve(lprec)
```

The vector "MyConstraint" is different in every iteration, but it has length 410 where 408 elements are 0 and two elements are 1.

That is, I have 410 objects in total, and I want to choose a set of those objects (1 if an object chosen and 0 otherwise) such that the objective function is maximized. However, some pairs of objects are not allowed, and so each of the 49422 constraints specifies which two objects cannot be chosen chosen at once: each constraint says that the sum cannot be above 1.

So, my question is if there is any way to solve this? If not, how large can such problem be in order to be solvable?

Thank you!

EDIT: ---------------------------------------------

In the comments I was asked to provide an example, so here is it. A similar, but much smaller problem. Suppose we have 7 different objects, and these can allocated into 5 groups. Let us define the groups and the associated savings denoted by A:

```
MyGroups <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,1,0,
              0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
MyGroups <- matrix(MyGroups,nrow=5,ncol=7,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(MyGroups) <- paste0("Group", 1:5)
colnames(MyGroups) <- paste0("Object", 1:7)

A=c(50,30,100,100,200)
```

That is, group 1 consists of Object 1 and Object 5 (denoted by the first row in the matrix MyGroups). Such a group will give a saving of 50. Objective: to maximize the total saving by choosing the right groups. Problem: each object can only be a part of one group. For example, if group 2 is implemented, then group 3 cannot be implemented, since both groups require object 3. Here we see that the optimal solution is to choose Group 1 and Group 5, which will give a total saving of 50+200=250. I want to be able to find this for a bigger problem. So, first I can create a matrix with constraints where specifies which 2 groups cannot be implemented at the same time.

```
lprec2 <- make.lp(0, 5)
set.objfn(lprec2, A)
lp.control(lprec2, sense="max")
set.type(lprec2,c(1:5),"binary")

#Defining the constraints
for (i in 1:(5-1)){
  for (j in (i+1):5) {
    
    if(max(colSums(MyGroups[c(i,j),]))>1){
      #group i and group j cannot be together. Add constraint
      MyConstraint=integer(5)
      MyConstraint[c(i,j)]=1
      add.constraint(lprec2, MyConstraint, "<=", 1)
    }
  }
}

lprec2
```

This gives the following mixed integer problem:
[image: The final problem]

When I solve it, then the solution is:

```
solve(lprec2)
get.objective(lprec2)
get.variables(lprec2)
```

Which gives 250 and  (1 0 0 0 1) respectively.

In the original problem I have 410 possible groups, implying 410 decision variables. The number of constraints is 49422, but in all rows there are exactly two 1 and the remaining are 0.

If you could help me to solve such a problem, I would be happy :-). Thanks!

Comment: It is common when R is relying on an external package that when you interrupt the process you need to restart R. Really you're just using R as an interface to `lpSolve` package. Large integer programming problems can often take long times. You might be able to estimate the time needed if you run the problem with 1/16 of the constraints, then 1/8 of the constraints, then 1/4 of the constraints, and then 1/2 the constraints, and extrapolate a probable exponential growth of solution time.

Comment: Maybe look into the Alienor method: https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=119568

Comment: `for` loops in R can be performance killers. R vectorization generally obviates the necessity to use them.   I use the ompr platform: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/index.html  The syntax is very compact.  Matrix objects are usually added via direct indexing in a single line of code.  I can't help you more without knowing more about your problem.

Comment: "They were so concerned with whether they **could** they didn't stop to think whether they **should**  ."    Which is to ask: are you certain there isn't a better approach than dealing with 50k separate constraints?

Comment: Note that simple constraints like you have usually reduce the solution time of an integer problem.  Binary/integer programming algorithms use node branching strategies.  In a preprocessing step the solver should use the constraint matrix to eliminate all of the infeasible pair branches during the search.  Best to post your problem in its entirety for follow on advice so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: @SteveM - Thank you! regarding first comment with the for loop. This part is not a problem. The loop simply adds the constraints one-by-one, and it takes about 1 min. Regarding the second comment - I am an expert in how the algorithm works, so if I can change the algorithm, then I will be happy to try. I have added an example to the post. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you. Now I understand why I need to restart R.

Comment: @jblood94 Thank you! Will take a look. I have now also added an example to my post.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you. So far I do not have a better approach, but I am looking into it. I have now also added an example to my post.

Comment: Avacado, thanks for the updated question.  I'll have a look.  SteveM.

Comment: @Avocado, how many objects comprise your 410 possible groups?

Comment: @jblood94 I have 32 objects. The solution below seems to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the model formulated using ompr:

```
MyGroups <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,1,0,
              0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
MyGroups <- matrix(MyGroups,nrow=5,ncol=7,byrow=TRUE)

ngroups <- nrow(MyGroups)
nobjects <- ncol(MyGroups)

coeffs <- c(50, 30, 100, 100, 200)

model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(group[i], i=1:ngroups, type = 'binary') %>% 
  add_variable(assign[i, j], i=1:ngroups, j=1:nobjects, type = 'binary', MyGroups[i, j] == 1) %>% 
  set_objective(sum_over(coeffs[i] * group[i], i=1:ngroups, sense = 'max')) %>% 
  add_constraint(sum_over(assign[i, j], i=1:ngroups, MyGroups[i, j] == 1) <= 1, j=1:nobjects) %>%
  add_constraint(assign[i, j] == group[i], i=1:ngroups, j=1:nobjects, MyGroups[i, j] == 1) %>% 
  add_constraint(sum_over(group[i], i=1:ngroups) <= 2)

result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI("glpk", verbose = TRUE))
result
<SOLVER MSG>  ----
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.47
16 rows, 16 columns, 35 non-zeros
*     0: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (11)
*    12: obj =  2.500000000e+002  infeas = 0.000e+000 (3)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.47
16 rows, 16 columns, 35 non-zeros
16 integer variables, all of which are binary
Integer optimization begins...
+    12: mip =     not found yet <=              +inf        (1; 0)
+    13: >>>>>  2.500000000e+002 <=  2.500000000e+002   0.0% (1; 0)
+    13: mip =  2.500000000e+002 <=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
<!SOLVER MSG> ----
result
Status: success
Objective value: 250
```

ompr is a model management wrapper around the ROI package.  It using an algebraic paradigm like GAMS or AMPL but has less embedded logic to simplify the syntax.  Although with ompr, you can test other solvers that ROI offers as plug-ins: http://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/

Some are free, others like Mosek, CPLEX and Gurobi are commercial products.  Suggest running a large subset problem and checking the relative performance of the different solvers.

Also note that your toy problem is degenerate.  Group(1, 3, 4) is also a solution.  I added an additional constraint that can limit the number of groups selected.  If your objective function coefficients are integer values the formulation may have many degenerate solutions, a simple test is to add a small random epsilon to each of the coefficients to eliminate degeneracy and see if that improves performance.

Comment: Wow! @SteveM , thank you so much. I could not use it directly, but then I added packages magrittr, ROI, ompr, ROI.plugin.glpk, ompr.roi. Then also it looks like there is a mistake in one line. Instead of
`  add_constraint(sum_over(assign[i, j], i=1:ngroups, MyGroups[i, j] == 1) <= 1, j=1:ngroups) %>%
`

it looks like it should be 
`add_constraint(sum_over(assign[i, j], i=1:ngroups, MyGroups[i, j] == 1) <= 1, j=1:nobjects) `

And, even though I haven't yet checked in details, it now looks like it works - amazing!

Comment: I haven't yet understood how exactly this works, but will look into it in the next week. All these packages are new to me. But once again, thank you! If you can refer to some websites or documents which are good to be able understand the method that you have provided, please let me know.

Comment: Right, that index was incorrect.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Again, the ompr page: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/index.html has the package info. That also has a link to the github repository. Note that the developer Dirk started a fork called MILPModel to supersede MIPModel.  That has been suspended.  MIPModel was updated with the additional MILPModel functionality but with simpler syntax.  Also please upvote the answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Keying in on a couple of the OP's statements:

> In the original problem I have 410 possible groups, implying 410
> decision variables. The number of constraints is 49422, but in all
> rows there are exactly two 1 and the remaining are 0.

and

> I have 32 objects.

It seems like this can be formulated as a maximum matching problem with a utility matrix instead of a preference matrix, which can be solved using the `maxmatching` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maxmatching/maxmatching.pdf).

The problem is set up using a savings matrix where the row and column indices refer to objects and each cell represents the savings for a group composed of two objects (the row and column).

First a smaller example with 7 objects and 15 groups:

```
library(igraph)
library(maxmatching)
library(Rfast)
set.seed(379327748)

n <- 7L # number of objects
m <- matrix(0L, n, n) # initialize the savings matrix
# specify the savings for the 15 groups in the lower triangle of the matrix
m[which(lower.tri(m))[sample(n*(n - 1L)/2L, 15)]] <- sample(1e3, 15, TRUE)
# the savings matrix: each cell refers to the savings for the row/column pair
m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]  692    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]  429    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [4,]  767  997  214    0    0    0    0
#> [5,]  133  146  966  835    0    0    0
#> [6,]  434  801  683    0  888    0    0
#> [7,]  619    0    0    0  513    0    0

# create a weighted graph using the savings matrix as a weighted adjacency
# matrix
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected", TRUE)
# Get the solution. The maxmatching function uses igraph::max_bipartite_match
# if bipartite.mapping(g)$res == TRUE and maxmatching::blossom otherwise. The
# two functions (confusingly) return the result in different formats.
groups <- if (bipartite.mapping(g)$res) {
  unique(rowSort(cbind(1:n, maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching)))
} else {
  matrix(maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}
# show the solution
groups
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    7
#> [2,]    2    4
#> [3,]    3    5
c(savings = sum(m[groups[,2:1]]))
#> savings 
#>    2582
```

Now an example with 32 objects and 410 groups. The solution is provided almost instantly.

```
n <- 32L
m <- matrix(0L, n, n)
m[which(lower.tri(m))[sample(n*(n - 1L)/2L, 410)]] <- sample(1e3, 410, TRUE)
system.time({
  g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected", TRUE)
  groups <- if (bipartite.mapping(g)$res) {
    unique(rowSort(cbind(1:n, maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching)))
  } else {
    matrix(maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  }
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.14    0.00    0.14
groups
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]    1   31
#>  [2,]    2   25
#>  [3,]    3   28
#>  [4,]    4   19
#>  [5,]    5   24
#>  [6,]    6    9
#>  [7,]    7   30
#>  [8,]    8   14
#>  [9,]   10   11
#> [10,]   12   13
#> [11,]   15   18
#> [12,]   16   21
#> [13,]   17   20
#> [14,]   22   32
#> [15,]   23   29
#> [16,]   26   27
c(savings = sum(m[groups[,2:1]]))
#> savings 
#>   14973
# check that each object is used only once
max(tabulate(groups, 32L))
#> [1] 1
```

Now a bipartite graph provided by the OP in the comments below.

```
n <- 8L
m <- diag(0, n)
m[cbind(c(7,4,8,6,5,6,8), c(1,2,2,3,4,5,7))] <- c(382579, 11817, 563242, 141901, 404604, 430947, 669989)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected", TRUE)
groups <- if (bipartite.mapping(g)$res) {
  unique(rowSort(cbind(1:n, maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching)))
} else {
  matrix(maxmatching(g, TRUE)$matching, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}

groups
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    7
#> [2,]    2    8
#> [3,]    3    6
#> [4,]    4    5
c(savings = sum(m[groups[,2:1]]))
#> savings 
#> 1492326
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just tried your solution. The way I understand it, here one assumes that an object can either be alone or be paired with someone else. It is not possible to allow larger groups, for instance, let 3 objects to be in a group. Is that correct? Thank you!

Comment: Correct. As I mentioned, this solution depends on your statement that "in all rows there are exactly two 1 and the remaining are 0." I have seen extensions of the stable roommate problem to triples (e.g., https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228816339_Stable_roommates_problem_with_triple_rooms), but I don't know of an R implementation.

Comment: I was testing your solution, and it looks like it gives wrong results (I could see it when comparing with the other method). Suppose we take a small example: 


 m2 <- matrix(0L,8,8) 
  m2[7,1]=382579
  m2[4,2]=11817
  m2[8,2]=563242
  m2[6,3]=141901
  m2[5,4]=404604
  m2[6,5]=430947
  m2[8,7]=669989
  
  m2[upper.tri(m2)] <- t(m2)[upper.tri(m2)]
  groups <- unique(rowSort(cbind(1:8, roommate(utils = m2))))
  c(savings = sum(m2[groups]))


 Then in the solution the total savings are 1112753 . However, there is a better solution (see next comment).

Comment: But this would be a better solution:

 groups2=c(1,7,4,5,3,6,2,8)
  groups2 <- matrix(groups2,nrow=4,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  
  c(savings = sum(m2[groups2]))

The total savings would be 1492326 . I cannot see where the error is. Maybe there is a problem with the package itself?

Comment: You're right. `roommates` is looking for a stable matching rather than a maximum utility matching. I've updated the answer to use the `maxmatching` package, which uses the blossom algorithm instead of Irving's algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, now it works. 

Do I understand it correctly that roommate function in matchingR package finds just one stable matching (where an agent is willing to reject the current partner and create a blocking pair with another partner if the shared amount is larger), but there can be several stable matchings, and the algorithm does not necessarily find the stable matching with highest total amount. Correct?

And regarding the new solution - it is still not possible to allow for groups with more than 2 agents, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your understanding matches mine on both accounts.